# Restricting to structured right homotopies

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, 2-categories

Let $\mathbf{Cat}$ be the 2-category of categories, functors, natural transformations. If $F, G : \mathscr C \to \mathscr D$ are functors, then natural transformations $\eta : F \Rightarrow G$ may be identified with functors $\eta : \mathscr C \times \mathbb I \to \mathscr D$ such that $\eta(-, 0) = F$ and $\eta(-, 1) = G$, where $\mathbb I = \{ 0 \to 1 \}$ is the interval category, or equivalently functors $\eta : \mathscr C \to \mathscr D^{\mathbb I}$ such that $\eta(-)(0) = F$ and $\eta(-)(1) = G$.

Consider some notion of structure $T$ on categories (for example, let $T$ be a 2-monad on $\mathbf{Cat}$, such as that for monoidal categories). We want to form a sub-2-category of $\mathbf{Cat}$ consisting of $T$-categories, $T$-preserving functors, and some kind of natural transformation. In particular, we may consider natural transformations that, as functors $\mathscr C \to \mathscr D^{\mathbb I}$, themselves preserve $T$-structure.

Often the category $\mathscr D^{\mathbb I}$ will inherit $T$-structure from $\mathscr D$ (usually pointwise, in the case of a 2-monad $T$). However, in some instances (such as if $T$ describes cartesian-closed structure), we will need to restrict to $T$-categories that have extra structure (such as finite limits).

This situation has a homotopical flavour: consider structure-preserving continuous maps between structured spaces, and then restrict to the right homotopies that also preserve that structure (possibly restricting the spaces in order for this to be well-defined). It seems like a natural construction in a general homotopical setting, but I am unfamiliar with homotopy theory. Is there a name for this process (ideally in an abstract setting, such as that of model categories), and has it been well-studied?

As a motivating example, if we take natural transformations between monoidal functors, that are themselves monoidal as right homotopies (in a canonical way), we get the standard notion of monoidal natural transformation.